# How do i list all consuming program by cpu, memory

Tags: process, memory, cpu, top, ram

I wanna list down all consuming cpu, memory programs.
there are bunch of top and questions about it, but all of them not list them by programs.
like for example a python webservice could spawn multiple processes.

i wanna sum all of them if they are from the same path or program id.

is there a chance to group and list them by `ppid` or `path`?

Comment: I wrote a [script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674717/get-memory-cpu-usage-by-application/675058#675058) a time ago, so maybe it could be useful for you.

Comment: I suppose you know top and htop and that they don't suit your needs

Comment: Did you try my script? Does it meet your requirements?